# How to access a variable in Polymorphism with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to access the `size` variable in each of the polymorphic methods. When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
examples.rb:181:in `calculate_area': undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from examples.rb:175:in `calculate_area'
        from examples.rb:199:in `<main>'
```

I have tried numerous hacks but haven't come up with a good solution. Here is the code below.

```
class Shape    

    attr_accessor :size

    def calculate_area(shape_type)
        shape_type.calculate_area
    end
end

class Circle < Shape
    def calculate_area
        return Math::PI * (size / 2) * (size / 2)
    end
end

class Square < Shape
    def calculate_area
        return size * size
    end
end

class Triangle < Shape
    def calculate_area
        return 0.5 * (size * 2) * size
    end
end

shape = Shape.new
shape.size = 5
puts shape.calculate_area(Circle.new)
puts shape.calculate_area(Square.new)
puts shape.calculate_area(Triangle.new)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're running it in wrong way. You should create instances of concrete shapes and then call methods on them:

```rb
[8] pry(main)> circle = Circle.new
=> #<Circle:0x0000563ed7328770>
[9] pry(main)> circle.size = 5
=> 5
[10] pry(main)> circle.calculate_area
=> 12.566370614359172
```

Comment: I ran it on my rails console. I am getting the same error: `undefined method / for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: "Methods defined with `attr_accessor` are not inherited". Yes, they are. The article you link mentions class-level accessors. Your edit is the right answer though. I suggest you remove the first part.

Comment: @User123 As an aside, this is just simple inheritance, not polymorphism.